# Redirecting the "parray" output to a file in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have an array in tcl. 
For example:

```
set a(1) "First element"
set a(2) "second element"
parray a
```

`parray a` displays output as

```
a(1) = "First element"  
a(2) = "second element"
```

Is it possible to redirect the `parray` output to a file?

Comment: You can override `parray` with `rename` command, to add your own idea.  Do `info body parray`. You have the `parray` code now and play with it. Or, you can override `puts` itself. (Since `parray` uses `puts` to print on the console)

Comment: i am not getting. can you please give an example?

Answer (score 4):

The `parray` command can't be redirected. It's a simple-minded procedure that is too stupid to be redirected. But it's [source code](https://core.tcl.tk/tcl/raw/library/parray.tcl?name=a0b1bd4e68dce1768d3c5e0d3c7b31e28021d3ba) isn't very long; in fact, it's short enough that I'll just paste it here (it's under the Tcl license):

```
proc parray {a {pattern *}} {
    upvar 1 $a array
    if {![array exists array]} {
        return -code error "\"$a\" isn't an array"
    }
    set maxl 0
    set names [lsort [array names array $pattern]]
    foreach name $names {
        if {[string length $name] > $maxl} {
            set maxl [string length $name]
        }
    }
    set maxl [expr {$maxl + [string length $a] + 2}]
    foreach name $names {
        set nameString [format %s(%s) $a $name]
        puts stdout [format "%-*s = %s" $maxl $nameString $array($name)]
    }
}
```

Redirecting it (hint: change the `stdout` for something obtained from `open … a`, and don't forget to `close` it afterwards) should be a simple exercise.

Comment: If you want to see the source on a tcl shell: `auto_load parray;info args parray;info body parray`

Answer (score 0):

This builds on the answers by Dinesh and Donal Fellows: You could adapt the code of `parray` automatically, like this:

```
auto_load parray

proc printArray {a {pattern *} {channel stdout}} \
    [string map {stdout $channel} [info body parray]]
```

This gives you a new proc `printArray` with an optional channel argument.